# What could cause getSkuDetails() to return null?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I recently lost the keystore for my Android application (before it was published) so I needed to create a new application on the Play store developer console, change my package name, and etc.

After doing that, my in app billing implementation broke: when I use `queryInventoryAsync()` on my `IabHelper`, it seems to think there is nothing in my inventory. I'm sure there is just something I forgot to update in my developer console or something like that, but I am not sure what.

Things I've checked:

1. The in app product I want the SkuDetails on is active.
2. The sku we are asking for in the query do actually exist on google play.
3. The product has not already been purchased.

What else might be missing?

Comment: have you purchased the product before this?

Comment: IM having a similiar problem, some times I get the full list of requested SKUs and sometimes I get some (and the rest are NULL)...

Answer (score 2):

This happens most of times, after Google changed the way things work on the Developer Play Store.

**Before**, we only had to upload signed APK without publishing it.

**Now**, there are sections Beta and Alpha where you have to upload signed APK and **publish it** in order to user in-app purchasing. Don't forget to add yourself to the tester list and properly set a list of beta users.